# How to pass attributes from knife command (ssh)?

Tags: chef-solo, knife, chef

Is it possible to attributes from knife command (ssh),

e.g.

```
knife ssh ‘role:server’ ‘sudo chef-client’ <-- how to pass attributes to remote?
```

Comment: Can't this be done through the "-j" option for chef-client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the attributes you want on the node object(s) on the Chef Server.

You can do this through a variety of methods.

- Add the attributes to the role you've applied to the nodes - this probably the best for systems that are all in a single role.
- Modify the node(s) directly, with knife node edit, or script it with [knife exec](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Knife+Exec).
- Set the attributes in an environment, if you're using those.